# How to get a caller's name and argument in Python?

Tags: python, function

**What is the problem**

I have a set of functions and all of them have only one argument, `x`.

When the number of functions is very big, I have problems with calculations (e.g. `RecursionError`). I want to know beforehand which functions depend on which, then start calculations with the functions that don't depend on others and cache their results. In that way, I will be able to calculate all functions.

For example:

```
def func_a(x):
    if x == 1:
        return func_b(x)
    return func_a(x-1) + func_c(x+1)


def func_b(x):
    return x


def func_c(x):
    return func_b(x)
```

**What I want**

What I want is to provide a tuple like `(func_a, 5)` which is a function name and its argument and receive which functions were called and with which arguments (`[(func_b, 4), (func_c, 6)]`).

```
(func_a, 5) --> [(func_b, 4), (func_c, 6)]
```

Other examples:

```
(func_a, 1) --> [(func_b, 1)]
(func_c, 3) --> [(func_b, 3)]
(func_b, 1) --> []
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried `@lru_cache` and it doesn't help because of the `RecursionError`.

```
print(func_a(500))
```

gives:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I was also looking into the `inpect` module but couldn't find anything to help with this one.

Comment: I interpret what you're saying as two things: "I want to know beforehand which functions depend on which, then start calculations with the functions that don't depend on others and cache their results." -> can be done with `@lru_cache` because functions will already call their dependencies, so their dependencies will finish first and get cached. "I want is to provide a tuple ... and receive which functions were called" -> can be done dynamically by recording method calls or statically by source parsing.

Comment: @Kache, thanks, I already tried `@lru_cache` but it doesnt help with recursion - I added this point to the post. 

What do you mean by 'recording method calls'?

I think statically source parsing will be very difficult because of the if-statements etc.

Comment: I think you're being a bit too hypothetical here. Is this an XY problem? Are you trying to debug/optimize recursive algorithms in general or are you just trying to exec some particular recursive computation? e.g. your `func_a()` could be replaced with `x*(x + 1)/2 + x - 1`, which avoids any recursion computation issues.

Answer (score 1):

If your algorithm bumps into a platform limitation, either

- adapt your algorithm, or
- fix/change the platform.

Possible ways include:

- Switch to an equivalent iterative algorithm
- https://pypi.org/project/tail-recursive/
- offload chunks of work to subprocesses via [`miltiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) when you're nearing the call stack depth limit
- Use an alternative Python implementation (e.g. PyPy optimizes recursion somewhat by e.g. inlining function calls) or another language with e.g. tail call optimization

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case somebody has a similar issue.

To get the list of caller functions, one can use the `ast` package and the `NodeVisitor` class in particular. The `visit_Call` method goes into all function calls, so we can gather the names of the functions.

Example:

```
class Visitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.funcs = set()

    def visit_Call(self, node):
        self.funcs.add(node.func.id)


def get_calls(func):
    visitor = Visitor()
    code = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(func))
    visitor.visit(code)
    return visitor.funcs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(get_calls(func_a))
```

Hope that helps.